# Database Design Form with many options

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating a web application that allows users to add products; however, for each product there might be 10 to 20 questions like the following:

```
Is the product good for:
[ ] children [ ] teenagers [ ] adults [ ] seniors
Categories that apply:
[ ] fun [ ] puzzle [ ] technical [ ] necessity [ ] fashion [ ] other: _____
Is product unique? [ ]
if yes explain how _______________
```

There is also potential for more questions to be added by users. What is the best way to store this kind of data, both the questions and the responses. The main takeaways are that there can be multiple boxes checked in many cases and that more questions can be added.

Initially my plan was to just have a `products` table with nullable booleans for each possible checkbox. If there was no dynamic adding of questions it would technically work but the table size was getting to be quite large, which I didn't particularly like but also wasn't sure was an issue for any technical reason.

I have thought about something like:

```
forms
-----
  id (PK)
  name
  owner_id (FK to users.id)
  (other fields)

form_elements
-------------
  id (PK)
  form_id (FK to forms.id)
  element_type_id (FK to element_types.id)
  caption
  (other fields)

element_types
-------------
  id (PK)
  name

element_list_values
-------------------
  id (PK)
  element_id (FK to form_elements.id)
  name
  value
  (other fields??)
```

Which seems to make a lot of sense on the storing created forms side but I'm struggling with how exactly you would store the results of these forms.

Comment: Should the forms be answerable by multiple users as well? Or just 1 answer set per product?

Comment: 1 answer set per product

Comment: "Categories that apply" implies that multiple boxes could be checked.  That sounds like a datatype `SET`.  If it is multiple-choice, it should be radio buttons and datatype `ENUM`.

Comment: What have you found from googling, eg re 'survey', 'questionaire' etc db designs? Read re pros & cons of EAV.

Answer (score 2):

I am initially thinking of two strategies, a traditional relational db method and a JSON method.

**Traditional method**

Since only 1 answer set per product is needed, you can store the value in the same table you define your answer items (I think it's `element_list_values` in your design). Here's an idea:

```
forms
-----
form_id             int  PK
product_id          int FK to product table

questions
---------
question_id         int PK
form_id             int FK to forms table
question_text       varchar

answers
-------
answer_id           int PK
question_id
answer_field_type   enum('textbox', 'checkbox')
answer_text         varchar
answer_value        varchar /* store answers here */
```

A sample of the table data would be as follows:

```
forms
-----
form_id     product_id
1           1

questions
---------
question_id form_id question_text
1           1       Is the product good for
2           1       Categories that apply

answers
-------
answer_id   question_id field_type  answer_item answer_value
1           1           checkbox    Children
2           1           checkbox    Teenagers   true
3           1           text        Others      Infants
```

Pros: fully relational, searchable
Cons: A little complex

**JSON method**

This method stores the entire form in 1 field as a JSON object (or XML if you're more comfortable with that, or a serialized object). Here's an idea:

```
forms
-----
form_id             int  PK
product_id          int FK to product table
questions           text (or json if your db has it)
```

The forms will stored in the `questions` column with the answers like this:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "Is the product good for:"
            "answers": [
                {
                    "item": "Children",
                    "type": "checkbox",
                    "value": ""             
                },
                {
                    "item": "Teenagers",
                    "type": "checkbox",
                    "value": "true"                             
                },
                {
                    "item": "Others",
                    "type": "text",
                    "value": "Infants"                              
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you need the answers to be searchable, you can store the answers/tags on another table that you can query.

Pros: simpler design, more flexible, easy to implement -- just JSON serialize an object to store and JSON parse to read. Cons: may be hard to search.

Anyway these are just ideas so adjust them as necessary for your needs.

Comment: While I'm leaning towards the JSON method at this point, I am curious about your first solution. I don't really see how you would functionally store different product answers.

Comment: Updated the answer to include sample data